# Inno Setup Compiler: installed Python file closes immediately

Tags: python-3.x, installation, exe

I've wrote in Python a program which I made to an exe file. For those file I created an installer with Inno Setup Compiler. 
If I start the installed exe file, I can only see the windows cmd for a short moment.
The problem is: if I start the exe file without installation (starting the exe) is everything working. Has anyeone an idea where the probleme could be?
I realizie in the script the "for ever shown" with

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
```

and some print statements and functions which aren't important. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: You need to give more information.  Normally, when I'm writing the installer for a program, I start with a clean system, copy all of the files needed to make the program work over, make sure it works, then build the installer from that list.  You say the cmd window shows for a short period of time.  Is there error logs or text that tells you why the program isn't running?  Is it missing something?  You need to debug what you're doing.  We don't know what your program or installer is doing.

Comment: There's no error but I found the problem: I choiced for the installer only a folder (in which the files are installed) and not the particularly files of the exe.